# AWS SDK C++ cmake problems CXX id unknown even with Environment Variable

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to add the AWS SDK for C++ into my Netbeans 8.2 Project http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-cpp/v1/developer-guide/setup.html

I have downloaded and unzipped the folder and installed cmake, but when I try to run cmake and create the library I get this error.

```
C:\Users\jense\Desktop\code libraries\aws-sdk-cpp-master\aws-sdk-cpp-master>"C:\Users\jense\Desktop\code libraries\cmake-3.8.2-win64-x64\cmake-3.8.2-win64-x64\bin\cmake" .
-- Could NOT find Git (missing:  GIT_EXECUTABLE)
-- TARGET_ARCH not specified; inferring host OS to be platform compilation target
-- Building AWS libraries as shared objects
-- Generating windows build config
-- Building project version: 1.1.10
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:105 (project):
  The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:

    cl

  is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

  To use the NMake generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
  that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
  unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
  Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/jense/Desktop/code libraries/aws-sdk-cpp-master/aws-sdk-cpp-master/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/jense/Desktop/code libraries/aws-sdk-cpp-master/aws-sdk-cpp-master/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

So, theres 2 things that point out to me, `cl` not being a full path and `CXX compiler identification unknown`. It seems like the error with `cl` is because of the preceeding `CXX compiler id is unknown` and that this `cl` error wouldnt happen if the id of my CXX compiler as known. I think this mostly because the rest of the message details how to specify my CXX compiler. However, I have tried setting an environment variable but I still receive the same error, so what am I doing wrong?

I created an environment variable on my computer with the name `CXX` and the value `C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe`, having also tried `C:\MinGW\bin\g++`

The same error and message occurs, how do I get around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, I created the environment variable correctly, but it was being overridden by the `CMakeCache.txt` file, I changed `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=cl` to `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH="C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe"`

I have no idea how `cl` was ever put there as the `C++` compiler path, but you need to modify the `CMakeCache.txt` file, as the environment variable was not enough.